How can I disable file splitting when compiling via Vite?
I have Laravel installed and there is a config like this
`
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
return {
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
               /// Heaps of files are being connected
            ],
            refresh: true,
        })
    ],
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/build',
        minify: 'esbuild',
        modulePreload: false,
        polyfillModulePreload: false,
        sourcemap: mode !== 'production',
        terserOptions: {
            compress: {
                drop_console: mode === 'production',
            },
            output: {
                comments: mode === 'production',
            },
        },
    },
}
});

`
And I want one file to be compiled and output, but now I have a file with this connection @vite(['resources/js/client/pages/client/sale/sale.js'])
and I want him to be the only one connected, but I'm past connecting him, that's all that's going on
<link rel="modulepreload" href="https://hitno.local/build/assets/constant-jYRDAREv.js"> <link rel="modulepreload" href="https://hitno.local/build/assets/init-swiper-CYD-sbV2.js"> <link rel="modulepreload" href="https://hitno.local/build/assets/pagination-BSD8aAhp.js"> <script type="module" src="https://hitno.local/build/assets/sale-CrTjuH8L.js"></script>
And I wish I didn't have a preload module at all, but just connected one file that I specified
I tried to figure it out on my own, but apart from the module Preload and polyfillModulePreload parameters, I didn't really find anything, but they don't help

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            laravel({
                input: [
                    'resources/js/client/pages/client/sale/sale.js', // specify only the file you want to compile
                ],
                refresh: true,
            }),
        ],
        build: {
            outDir: 'public/build',
            minify: 'esbuild',
            modulePreload: false,
            polyfillModulePreload: false,
            sourcemap: mode !== 'production',
            rollupOptions: {
                output: {
                    manualChunks: undefined, // disables code splitting
                },
            },
            terserOptions: {
                compress: {
                    drop_console: mode === 'production',
                },
                output: {
                    comments: mode === 'production',
                },
            },
        },
    };
});

Explanation
•   input: Specify only the file you want as the main entry point.
•   manualChunks: undefined: By setting manualChunks to undefined, you’re disabling Vite’s automatic chunking behavior, which will prevent additional chunks from being generated.
•   modulePreload and polyfillModulePreload: false: This prevents Vite from generating additional <link rel="modulepreload"> tags in the HTML output.

With this setup, Vite should compile all code into a single output file without generating additional preload or module chunks. This should give you a single  tag for the specified entry file. Let me know if this achieves the result you’re looking for!

I did everything, but nothing has changed for me.
